# Release [] in namespace [] already exists but is not managed by the current context. Applying changes will likely cause conflicts

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

Is there any way to manage existing helm releases with **helmsman** which are deployed using **helm** ?
Consider we have a release which is deployed with below command:

```
helm install my-release repo/chart
```

Now we want update my-release using helmsman without deleting existing release. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and the solution was to set the context via helmsman first and then the apply worked, no need to delete the existing release.

For example:

1. This will set the release context for whatever the value of the property *context* is in the `app.yaml` file

```
$ cat app.yaml
contex: foo
[...]

$helmsman -f app.yaml --migrate-context
```

2. after this the context will be set to *foo* in the helm release and you can use helmsman again